# Laravel complex query with eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to laravel and eloquent and I can't find an example of what I'm trying to do , lets say I have three tables A B C , and all of them have many to many relations ships `A - ab - B - bc - C.`

```
ab : table contains key from A and B.
bc : table contains key from B and C.
```

What to do if I want to find C objects using A (a_id = 1) ?

I tried something like this `A::find(1) -> B() -> C()->get() ;`

```
B() is method i created to get B objects in A model.
C() is method i created to get C objects in B model.
```

What am I doing wrong ?
I hope the question and the example are clear.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You might want to format your examples a little more. If it's more legible folks will be more apt to help. Try the { } buttoton for code snippets.

Answer (score 2):

Eloquent offers a [`hasManyThrough`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) relationship shortcut, but that only supports **one-to-many** relations between the models. There are various workarounds in [this thread](http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many) on the Laravel.io Forum. The following is a short solution taken from [that thread](http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many?page=1#reply-11997) that I've tested and has worked. This needs to be added to a base model that your models will extend:

```php
public function manyThroughMany($related, $through, $firstKey, $secondKey, $pivotKey)
{
    $model = new $related;
    $table = $model->getTable();
    $throughModel = new $through;
    $pivot = $throughModel->getTable();

    return $model
        ->join($pivot, $pivot . '.' . $pivotKey, '=', $table . '.' . $secondKey)
        ->select($table . '.*')
        ->where($pivot . '.' . $firstKey, '=', $this->id);
}
```

Then on your `A` model you can define a relation method that returns this:

```php
public function c()
{
    return $this->manyThroughMany('C', 'B', 'b_id', 'id', 'c_id');
}
```

And access the related entries like so:

```
A::find(1)->c()->get();
```

There's also a [class defining a relation](http://laravel.io/forum/03-04-2014-hasmanythrough-with-many-to-many?page=1#reply-25585) for this very purpose also in that thread, but I haven't tested it so I can't say if it works properly.